# C/C++ program for checking MySQL connectivity and InnoDB plug-ins

Tags: c++, mysql, c, innodb

I need a C/C++ program that connects to a MySQL server and checks if the InnoDB data store is installed on it.

The program should print the total number of disk writes by MySQL onto the InnoDB store.

Comment: If you can, please elaborate on the need to find no. of disk writes by MySql. It would be better if you could give a background. It will help people visualize the scenario in a better way to think of a answer closer to what you need, plus it will be a good information for other readers

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
Below program is compiled using GCC and tested in Ubuntu 11.04 and    Maynot run properly run in windows because of header file.
Make sure MySQL is installed properly.
*/
 #include<stdio.h>  
 #include<string.h>
 #include<mysql.h>
 //#include<conio.h> //Uncomment if you are using windows
 int main()
 {
     MYSQL *connection;//pointer to connection string, MYSQL structure pointer
     MYSQL_RES *result;//pointer holds result
     MYSQL_ROW row;//stores a row  in result

     char *server = "localhost";//server is localhost since MySQL runs in same machine
     char *user = "root";//username to connect to DB
     char *password = "pass";//Password
     char *database = "blog";//DB name

     connection = mysql_init(NULL);//Getting ready for MySQL Connection

     if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, server, user, password, database,
     0, NULL, 0))//Establishing connection with parameters
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection));//PRINT Error message 
        exit(1);//In case unable to connect quit
     }

     /*
       show engines will display all the engines available.Sample  Output 
       mysql> show engines;
       +------------+---------+------------------------------------    ----------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
       | Engine     | Support | Comment                                                          | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
       +------------+---------+------------------------------------ ----------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
       | InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
       | MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM  tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
       | BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
       | CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
       | MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
       | FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
       | ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
       | MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
       +------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
       8 rows in set (0.00 sec)


       */
       if(mysql_query(connection, "show engines"))
       {
            fprintf(connection, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection));
            exit(1);//EXit when query failed
       }

       result = mysql_use_result(connection);//fetch result pointer
       printf("\n --- Output ---- \n");
       while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL)//iterating over the result
       {
             if((strcmp(row[0], "InnoDB") == 0) && strcmp(row[1], "YES") == 0)
             printf("InnoDB engine is supported\n");
             break;
        }
        mysql_free_result(result);//Free the buffer 

        //To fetch Total writes
        if(mysql_query(connection, "show global status"))
        {
             fprintf(connection, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection));
             exit(1);//EXit when query failed
        }

        result = mysql_use_result(connection);//fetch result pointer
        while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL)//iterating over the result
        {
              if(strcmp(row[0], "Handler_write") == 0)
              printf("\nTotal Writes : %d\n", row[1]);
         }

         mysql_free_result(result);//Free the buffer 
         mysql_close(connection);//close the connection

         //getch(); //uncomment this line if you are using windows.
         return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 Program    :InnoDB_checker.c
 Description:Write a C/C++ program that connects to a MySQL server and checks if the              InnoDB plug-in is installed on it.
        If so, your program should print the total number of disk writes by MySQL.
 Date       :7/09/2011
 Version    :1.0
 Author     :Venugopal Madathil*/
 /*Command to run the program: gcc -o output -I/usr/include/mysql/ -lmysqlclient InnoDB_checker.c -w */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<mysql.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{ 
        MYSQL *connection;
        MYSQL_RES *result;
        MYSQL_ROW *row;


//printf("\nI'm here\n");//Debugger
char *server = "localhost";//Since system itself acts as the server
//Credentials initialization
char *user = "root";
char *password = "pass";//Must 
char *database = "webyog";//Must be an existing database name
int numfields,Inno_flag=0,CSV_flag=0,c;
char choice;

do
{
    system("clear");//To clear the terminal screen
    printf("----------------------\nPlug-in checker\n");
    printf("----------------------\n");
    connection = mysql_init(NULL);//Allocates or initializes a MYSQL object suitable for mysql_real_connect,if NULL it returs a new object
    if(!mysql_real_connect(connection,server,user,password,database,0,NULL,0))//Connection establishment
    {
        printf("\nConnection error:");
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",mysql_error(connection));//Error
    }
    if(mysql_query(connection,"show engines"))
    {
        printf("\nQuery execution failed:");
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",mysql_error(connection));//Error
    }
    result = mysql_use_result(connection);//Fetching result
    numfields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    //printf("\nNumber of fields:%d\n",numfields);//Number of fields
    printf("What do you want to check?\nPress 1 for InnoDB\nPress 2 for CSV support\nYour choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    //
    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL)//Iterating result row
            {
                if((strcmp(row[0], "InnoDB") == 0) && strcmp(row[1], "YES") == 0)//Innodb plug in checking
                        Inno_flag=1;
                    if((strcmp(row[0], "CSV") == 0) && strcmp(row[1], "YES") == 0)//CSV support checking
                        CSV_flag=1;
            }
    switch(c)
    {
        case 1:

            if(!Inno_flag)
                printf("InnoDB plug-in is not installed\n");
            else
                printf("InnoDB plug-in is installed\n");
                mysql_free_result(result);//Freeing the buffer 
                //To fetch Total Disk writes by MySQL 
                if(mysql_query(connection, "show global status"))
                {
                printf("\nQuery execution failed:");
                    fprintf(connection, "%s\n", mysql_error(connection));
                    exit(1);
                }

                result = mysql_use_result(connection);//fetching result 
                while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL)//Iterating result row
                {
                     if(strcmp(row[0], "Handler_write") == 0)
                     printf("Total number of Disk Writes by MySQL: %d\n", row[1]);
                 }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(!CSV_flag)
                                    printf("CSV support is not there.\n");
                            else
                                    printf("CSV support is there.\n");

            break;
        default:printf("\nInvalid choice\n");

    }
    mysql_free_result(result);//Freeing the buffer
        mysql_close(connection);//closing the connection 
    printf("\nDo you want to continue?(Y/N):");
    scanf("%s",&choice);
    if(choice!='Y'|| choice!='y'||choice!='n'||choice!='N')
    {
        printf("\nInvalid option. Program exits.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}while(choice =='Y' || choice =='y' );
return 0;
    }
     //Command to run the program: gcc -o output -I/usr/include/mysql/ -lmysqlclient InnoDB_checker.c -w
```